# how to install Xubuntu Core?

Tags: xubuntu

I am a beginner of Linux.

I am interested to install Xubuntu Core on my HDD from a USB Stick.

I've read the MinimalCD documentation from here [Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) and the first point from the installation steps is "Acquire the correct Ubuntu installation files ('the ISO')"

Please someone help me to find the iso for Xubuntu Core. I've done my best to find it here [Introducing Xubuntu core](http://xubuntu.org/news/introducing-xubuntu-core/) but I couldn't.

Or, are there any other ways to make a fresh install of Xubuntu Core? Now I use Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Do you want to install XFCE (Xubuntus environment) or Xubuntu itself?

Comment: Sorry Eduardo, I am not so sure, I am interested to have a lightware, slim OS. I am interested to have Xubuntu Core with as fewer as possible pre installed applications as possible. I am interested to format the OS HDD partition and use only Xubuntu Core.  I hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you do not need to install Xubuntu from scratch. Boot Ubuntu, open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run the command ´sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop´. Insert your password and this will install XFCE, the desktop environment used by Xubuntu. This will keep all your installed programs, but will change your desktop. Then after the installation ended, you can reboot and choose XFCE in your login screen. If you want, you can remove Unity (Ubuntu default desktop) with the command ´sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop´.

Comment: If you want a REALLY fast desktop environment, why do not you try installing ´lubuntu-desktop´ instead of ´xubuntu-desktop´? It will install LXDE, the environment used by Lubuntu. It only takes 150 MB of RAM without any applications opened.

Comment: please read and follow the steps at your second link, thats it!

Comment: Currently core is an installation tasksel set you can at the end of installing with mini.iso with a very recent version instead of the LTS.  It would be described as minimal Xubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Ubuntu mini ISO from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) and copy to USB drive.

At the initial menu screen, choose the *install* option (should be selected by default) and follow the steps to configure as you wish..

After the base system has been installed, it will prompt you to pick a DE and other features. Select *Xubuntu minimal installation* and continue, following prompts as required.

You now have a fresh install of Xubuntu Core!

---

You can try this out first in a virtual machine if you are concerned.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-core^
```

Don't forget to include the caracter **^** at the end.